# How to retrieve a text file from the resource file in C# VS.2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, resources, embedded-resource

I have a html template that I want to retrieve from the resources file in a VS 2005 C# windows form application.

I've created a folder called /html/ within the project, which has one file in it called template.html.

I've added the file to my resources. I see its name just as template, and it's filepath is the fully qualified filename (c:/.../project/html/template.html). It is saved as TEXT rather than binary.

I've tried many methods to extract this file, but each time I get a null returned. What am I missing?

```
        Type t = GetType();
        Assembly a = Assembly.GetAssembly(t);
        string file = "html.template.html"; // I've tried template and template.html
        string resourceName = String.Concat(t.Namespace, ".", file);

        Stream str = a.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);

        if (str == null) // It fails here - str is always null.
        {
            throw new FileLoadException("Unrecoverable error. Template could not be found");
        }
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(str);
        htmlTemplate = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) at your output assembly to verify that the resource name is actually what you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1):

Reflector helped in finding out what the problem is, thank you. This is what I needed to have:

```
string template = Properties.Resources.template;
```

Couldn't be easier really. All the other stuff above was completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're misnaming your resource when you attemp to retrieve it.

One thing you could do is to examine the generated assembly with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and check the full name of your resource.